# js tests do not work when it s tsx files tested

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I'm facing a problem that's I do not really understand so I'm asking you to try to help me to fix and understand it.

I making tests since few days to stablasize my application. My application is compose as ReactJs and typeScript but my tests only wrote as Js (cause I suppose that was not very useful to type tests never mind)

So for ts tests it's work very fine 9 of 12 suites tests passed but 3 of 12 suites tests on tsx files and then don't realy work ...  seen like jest do note understand tsx files am I right ?

I got so error like this :

> ● Test suite failed to run

```
SyntaxError: /Users/***/function.spec.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (44:16)

  42 |     }
  43 |     wrapper = mount(
> 44 |       <Provider store={store}>
     |                 ^
  45 |         <HookWrapper />
  46 |       </Provider>
  47 |     );

  at Object._raise (../../../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/jest/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/error.js:60:45)
```

or other like :

> ● Test suite failed to run

```
SyntaxError: /Users/***/index.spec.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (32:34)

  30 |   it("Run file/index is ran", async () => {
> 32 |     wrapper = shallow(<ComponentFile {...minProps} />);
     |                                   ^
  33 |     expect(wrapper).toBeTruthy();
  34 |   });
  35 |

  at Object._raise (../../../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/jest/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/error.js:60:45)
```

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  verbose: true,
  collectCoverage: true,
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [],
  forceCoverageMatch: [" */*.spec.js"],
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js"],
};
```

I passed one day to understand what is wrong but nothing to do... I tried a lot of jest config cause I thought the problem came from it but I do not success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 2 full days I searched a lot about what happen and I figured out the problem!
I'm not sure that's gonna help everyone very one but for me it work.

I would like to said that's my feeling about the setup was great (the problem came from here ) but I was too focus on the babel.config.js / babel.config.js / tsconfig.js / and in general jest.config.js... but the thing is that I thought  steupTests.js was by default found by jest at the npm test / compilation (what ever) but I was totaly wrong and finaly I include it in my jest.config.js with `setupFilesAfterEnv: ["./src/setupTests.js"]` and now all of my suites tests passed

I give you my configs :

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    clearMocks: true,

    coverageDirectory: "coverage",
  
    coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/"],
  
    moduleNameMapper: {
      "\\.(css|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
    },
  
    testMatch: [
      // "**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)",
      "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x)",
    ],
  
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/"],

    verbose: true,
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ["./src/setupTests.js"],
  
  };
```

tsconfig.js :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "types": ["jest", "node"],
    "noEmit": true,
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

babel.config.js

```
// babel.config.js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        targets: {
          node: "current",
        },
      },
    ],
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
    "@babel/preset-react",
  ],
};
```

Hopefully it's gonna help some of you, Regards!