# React-scripts is ignoring tests that end in .tsx

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-scripts

I'm currently trying to convert my project to TypeScript, and it is almost working perfectly. All of my code builds, and I everything renders correctly. The only issue is my tests.

I've noticed that as soon as I rename a test file from `.test.jsx` to `.test.tsx`, the tests in that file stop being run by `react-scripts test`. Interestingly, files ending in `.test.ts` are still run, however renaming my component tests to just have the `.test.ts` file extension causes them to get syntax errors.

I have tried adding a `jest.config.js` that should match my TSX files, but it appears to have had no impact.

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  testMatch: ['**/__tests__/**/*.ts?(x)', '**/?(*.)+(spec|test).ts?(x)'],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
};
```

I have also tried adding the `setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./src/setupTests.js'],` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64425014/js-tests-do-not-work-when-it-s-tsx-files-tested), but to no avail.

How can I modify my setup so that I am able to have Jest match `.test.tsx` files?

Comment: `react-scripts` uses its own Jest configuration, I doubt your `jest.config.js` (which is pretty close to [the default](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testmatch-arraystring)) is being picked up at all. But that configuration _does_ pick up `.tsx` tests, at least with the TypeScript template (e.g. [this](https://github.com/textbook/abv/blob/main/src/App.test.tsx) gets run) - how exactly have you tried to convert your project?

Comment: Thanks, @jonrsharpe your comment pointed me in the right direction - turns out react-scripts uses its own configuration file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the default `react-scripts` configuration ignores `jest.config.js` files, and instead requires you to specify your configuration in the `package.json` file.

In the `jest` object of the `package.json`, I needed to add the following:

```json
{
  "testMatch": [ "**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)", "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)" ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `craco` package for custom configuration also (`craco.config.js`):

```
const path = require('path');    
  
module.exports = {
  jest: {
    configure: {
      preset: 'ts-jest',
      roots: ['<rootDir>'],
      modulePaths: ['<rootDir>/src'],
      moduleDirectories: ['node_modules'],
      transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/'],
      moduleFileExtensions: ['tsx', 'js', 'json', 'node', 'ts'],
      testEnvironment: 'jsdom'
    }
  }
};
```

And then in the `jest.config.js`:

```
const { createJestConfig } = require('@craco/craco');
const cracoConfig = require('./craco.config.js');
const jestConfig = createJestConfig(cracoConfig);

module.exports = jestConfig;
```

[Craco](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco) (Create React App Configuration Override) is a tool that allows you to override the default configuration of Create React App without `npm eject`.
It can help you with:

- support for Sass or Less,
- customizing the Babel configuration,
- customizing the Webpack configuration...